# Add Models and Controllers to Orchard

Tags: content-management-system, addition, orchardcms

Does anybody know how to create his own models and controllers in Orchard-based projects? I have an empty project and a pack of screenshots for pages, but I don't know with what to begin. If it is possible, please show an example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should start off at the [documentation page](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/). There is an 'Extending Orchard' section which walks you through how to create a module, with data access, content parts, and content fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line to generate the module using the [code generation module](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.CodeGeneration)

Documentation [here](http://orchardproject.net/docs/Command-line-scaffolding.ashx)

Then install the **[Code Generation Extensions](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Szmyd.CodeGeneration)** from Piotr and follow the instructions on his blog. http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/generating-orchard-content-parts-via-command-line

> Module adds an Orchard command-line command “codegen part”. It’s
>   syntax is as follows:
>
> > *codegen part   [/Properties:]*
>
> For example:
>
> > *codegen part Modules.Shop ProductPart /Properties: Name:string,
> >     Price:int*
>
> Properties is an optional parameter, so if you’d like to create an
>   empty part you can just write
>
> > *codegen part Modules.Shop ProductPart*
>
> The command creates a handler, driver, model, record, display and
>   editor shapes and updates the Placement.info file with default
>   Content:before placement for your part shape. If you provide
>   /Properties parameter, the model, record and editor shapes will be
>   filled with appropriate code accordingly.

Comment: Seems nice and easy. Thank you very much!!

Comment: And make sure you have no instances of your application running, it doesn't like that ;)